# Elite book 840 G2

Tags: laptop, motherboard, battery, laptop-repair, hp-elitebook

Please help me. I noticed that my laptop was on a spilled water on the table over night. I dismantled it and cleaned it up, dried it as much as I could from a warm temperature viz rays on the sun for a day.  Now it can only power and make a noise with the fan then goes off... don’t know what to do from here. Also when plugged in for a charge it doesn’t show light of power.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop…  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/119271

Comment: That, and 1. Do NOT power it up. Still water/still shorts circuit/still corrosion and electricity is bad idea. instead. 1. Check your backups. 2. Remove the HDD to safeguard your data. After that send it to someone able to recover it or get a new laptop.